# How to find all tags from string using RegEx using C#.net?

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation

I want to find all HTML tags from the input strings and removed/replace with some text.
suppose that I have string

**INPUT**=>

```
<img align="right" src="http://www.groupon.com/images/site_images/0623/2541/Ten-Restaurant-Group_IL-Giardino-Ristorante2.jpg" /><p>Although Italians originally invented pasta as a fastener to keep Sicily from floating away, <a href="http://www.tenrestaurantgroup.com/">Il Giardino Ristorante</a> in Newport Beach.</p>
```

**OUTPUT**=>

```
string strSrc="http://www.groupon.com/images/site_images/0623/2541/Ten-Restaurant-Group_IL-Giardino-Ristorante2.jpg";

<p>Although Italians originally invented pasta as a fastener to keep Sicily from floating away, http://www.tenrestaurantgroup.com in Newport Beach.</p>
```

From above string 
if `<IMG>` tag found then I want to get **SRC** of the  tag,
if `<A>` tag found then I want get **HREF** from the  tag.
and all other tag as same it is..

How can I achieved using Regex in C#.net?

Comment: Mandatory reading: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: This is a really simple regex. What do you need it for?

Comment: @sln I used HtmlAgilityPack for solve above problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for parsing (valid/non valid) html and get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

**[You really, really shouldn't use regex for this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)** In fact, parsing HTML cannot be done perfectly with regex. Have you considered using an XML parser or HTML DOM library?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Justin, Regex really isn't the best way to do this, and the HTML Agility is well worth a look if this is something you will need to be doing alot of.

With that said, the expression below will store attributes into a group from where you should be able to pull them into your text while ignoring the rest of the element. :

</?([^ >]+)( [^=]+?="(.+?)")*>

Hope this helps.